# Using php variable in javascript if-statement

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to pass on a `$_POST['foo']` variable to a JavaScript variable while I am using a php if- statement. But its not working. Any suggestions on how to make it run?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['foo']))    
{    
?>
<script>
var jFoo= <?php echo json_encode($_POST['foo']); ?>;
</script>
<?
}


 else {
    ...
    }
    ?>
```

---

EDIT:

This is weird: 
I was actually trying to make the code run like this (this wasnt working):

```
if(isset($_POST['foo']))    
{    
?>
<script>
var jFoo= <?php echo json_encode($foo); ?>;
</script>
<?
}
else {
...
}
```

However, when I just did this, it worked:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['foo']))    
{    
?>
<script>
var jFoo= <?php echo json_encode($_POST['foo']); ?>;
</script>
<?
}
else {
...
}
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Have you looked at the output HTML? Is it missing quote marks?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code you posted.  Why doesn't it work?  What errors do you get?  What is the output from your PHP script?

Comment: Posted variables are usually strings so you will need to change your code to var jFoo="<?php echo json_encode($_POST['foo']); ?>";

Comment: @jeff That's completely incorrect.  The JSON-encoding handles any quoting that is needed.  Adding additional quotes actually breaks this.

Comment: @jeff `$_POST` variables can also be arrays

Comment: Not working how, is there an error (if so what)? Your just assigning the variable `jFoo`, where are you testing that it's actually there?

Comment: Because `$foo = $_POST['foo'];` is outside of PHP, therefore `$foo` is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a simple change in your script and it works for me. I changed the code in line 9 from

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['foo']))    
{    
?>
<script>
var jFoo= <?php echo json_encode($_POST['foo']); ?>;
alert(jFoo);
</script>
<?php
}
else {

}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name='foo' />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code works normally:

```
        <form method="post" action="">
             <input type="text" name="foo"></input>
             <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
           <?php
              if(isset($_POST['foo'])) {
           ?>
           var jFoo = <?php echo json_encode($_POST['foo']); ?>;
           alert(jFoo); // test
           <?php } ?>
        </script>
```